# How to develop an android application separating data and view layer

Tags: android, kotlin

I am new to Android development. have an android application in koltin wherein  I have to make an http post request to get a list of data as response.
I have done that in activity class as follows.
MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), {

    private fun getAppList() {
        var builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this@MainActivity)
        builder.setTitle("App Response")
        doAsync {
            sslCertficate.disableSSLCertificateChecking()
            var headers = HashMap<String, String>()

            headers["Content-type"] = "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
            val res = HTTPClient("https://sample-myapi-launcher.prod.com/list")
                    .setMethod("POST")
                    .setHeaders(headers)
                    .setBody(getRequestBody(userInfo.toString()))
                    .getResponse()
                    .response
            uiThread {
                builder.setMessage(res)
                var dialog: AlertDialog = builder.create()
                dialog.show()
            }

            Log.e("Response List", res)

        } 
    }

    private fun getRequestBody(userInfo: String): String {
   //code for geting request body

    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigator)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
      //calling api request method
        getAppList()

    }
}
```

I could achieve my result through this, But I don't want to put all the work in the activity thread. Can someone guide on the correct approach to achieve this?
Or help me with some documentation.

Comment: read this https://android.jlelse.eu/8-ways-to-do-asynchronous-processing-in-android-and-counting-f634dc6fae4e

Comment: @PraveenP Thanks ,but this is bit difficult to follow. Is there any code samples?

Comment: Use retrofit with enqueue(..) method

Comment: @PraveenP That's an outdated article and not so relevant for Kotlin since modern alternatives exist.

Comment: @ZUNJAE it just a basic android way  to perform asynchronous tasks for beginner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the Android [lifecycle-aware components codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-lifecycles/#0). It will do exatelly what you ask for. Here is the [Architecture components](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/index.html) part of the Android Jetpack and it is a set of Android libraries that help you structure your app in a way that is robust, testable, and maintainable.

Here is also the [android-sunflower](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-sunflower) A gardening app illustrating Android development best practices with Android Jetpack.

Answer (score 0):

to do networking I suggest you to use Retrofit2: [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/)

Anyway to do networking operation in another thread you need to start a new AsyncTask from you activity and do the networking operations inside it.
In retrofit all this is much more simple!

(Sorry but I don't have Kotlin example for that below!)

## Java Example without Retrofit:

( This was a my old project, so it isn't so good ^^)

```
/* Really Simple Class I made to do networking operations (so use Retrofit or make a better one (: (I suggest you, again, to use Retrofit!) */
public class DBConnection {

    public String  performPostCall(String requestURL, HashMap<String, String> postDataParams )
    {

        URL url;
        String response = "";
        try {
            url = new URL(requestURL);

            HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            conn.setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
                @Override
                public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                    return true;
                }
            });
            conn.setSSLSocketFactory((SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault());
            conn.connect();

            DataOutputStream dStream = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
            dStream.writeBytes(getPostDataString(postDataParams));
            dStream.flush();
            dStream.close();

            int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                String line;
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                while ((line=br.readLine()) != null) {
                    response += line;
                }
            } else {
                response = "";
            }
            conn.disconnect();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return response;
    }

    private String getPostDataString(HashMap<String, String> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException
    {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        boolean first = true;
        for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()){
            if (first) {
                first = false;
            } else {
                result.append("&");
            }

            result.append(entry.getKey());
            result.append("=");
            result.append(entry.getValue());
        }

        return result.toString();
    }

}

// AsyncTask to do Async Networking operations:

public class YourTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private String yourData...;

    public YourTask(String token){
        // Set Your Data
    }
// "String..." is an array of arguments so you get the arguments usign: params[i]
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params)
    {
        DBConnection dbConn = new DBConnection();
        String stampAnswer;
        try{

            Integer param1 = Integer.parseInt(params[0]);
            Integer param2 = Integer.parseInt(params[1]);
            answer = dbConn.netwokirngOperation([..]);
        }catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
            nfe.getStackTrace();
            stampAnswer = "";
            Log.e("YourTask", " NumberFormatException:");
        }
        return answer;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Log.e("YourTask => ", " Result:" + result);
    }

}

// To call the task do in your activity and do async networking operation without wait for result (this mean you need to save the data inside Realm DB [REALM][2] or using SQLite DB and then get them when the networking operations ended (you can use an Observable and set it when the networking operation end, send a broadcast message and set a receiver in you activity, or any other method):

new YourTask(<put_here_your_asynctask_constructor_args>).execute(params);

// To call the task and do async networking operation but wait to get the result returned by the "doInBackground" method of the AsyncTask:

new YourTask(<put_here_your_asynctask_constructor_args>).execute(params).get();
```

But is better if you use interface and callback to return the result from the AsyncTask when it ended, example:

```
/** in You Activity. Because in the Interface you use generic types (the 'T') you can specific the type of object returned by the interface inside the '<T>' if the interface WILL ALWAYS RETURN THE SAME OBJECT TYPE! 
If it WILL RETURN DIFFERENT OBJECT TYPES you MUST don't specific the type inside the '<T>', but you have to cast the return inside a switch statement to know which object is returned (to do that you can add a 'int requestCase' to the interface so you know which case returned!) **/

public class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity 
    implements IYourCallback<YourObjectTypesReturned>{

     public interface IYourCallback<T>{
          onNetOperationSuccess(List<T> answer)
          onNetOperationError(Throwable t)
     }

     /** IMPLEMENTS HERE YOUR ACTIVITY BODY WITH THE INTERFACE METHODS ! **/

     // Then call your AsyncTask where you want and pass it your context which implements the interface ( because you are in activity your context with the interface is "this"!

     new YourTask(this).execute(params);

// Then inside your AsyncTask:

public class YourTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        private IYourCallback mCallback;

        public YourTask(Context context){
            try{
               mCallback = (IYourCallback) mCallback;
            } catch(ClassCastException e){
                  onException(e);  // Manage the exception and stop the operation
             }
        }

        /** THEN IMPLEMENT YOU IN BACKGROUND... AND WHEN THE NETWORKING OPERATION IS FINISHED USE THE CALLBACK TO RETURN BACK YOUR RESULT, SO THE METHOD IN YOUR ACTIVITY WILL GET TRIGGERED AND YOU CAN CONTINUE TO DO YOUR OPERATIONS! So do: **/

if(success)
   mCallback.onNetOperationSuccess(myListAnswer)
else
   mCallback.onNetOperationError(error) // Throwable or exception
```

( Kotlin for the implementation of Retrofit! I started use Kotlin 5 days ago, so I don't know if this is the best use (: )

## Example with Retrofit:

```
/* This is a RetrofitHelper which init the Retrofit instance and where you should put your networking methods. Then to do a networking operation you have to get this instance using (RetrofitHelper.getInstance().yourNetworkingOperation(...) ).
Anyway here there isn't the asynchronous part, you can get it in the link of my other comment below!
```

I don't have complete this class yet! */
    class RetrofitHelper(baseUrl: String){

```
    private val TAG = this.javaClass.name
    // Timeouts
    private val CONNECT_TIMEOUT = "CONNECT_TIMEOUT"
    private val READ_TIMEOUT = "READ_TIMEOUT"
    private val WRITE_TIMEOUT = "WRITE_TIMEOUT"
    // Header Names
    private val BASE_REQ_HEADER_NAME = "BLEDataBinder"
    private val REQ_HEADER_NAME = "$BASE_REQ_HEADER_NAME.Request"
    private val REQ_HEADER_VERSION_NAME = "$BASE_REQ_HEADER_NAME.VersionName"
    private val REQ_HEADER_VERSION_CODE = "$BASE_REQ_HEADER_NAME.VersionCode"
    private val REQ_HEADER_DEVICE_IMEI = "$BASE_REQ_HEADER_NAME.DeviceIMEI"
    private val REQ_HEADER_DEVICE_UNIQUE_ID = "$BASE_REQ_HEADER_NAME.DeviceUniqueID"
    private val REQ_HEADER_DEVICE_MODEL = "$BASE_REQ_HEADER_NAME.DeviceModel"
    private val REQ_HEADER_ANDROID_RELEASE = "$BASE_REQ_HEADER_NAME.AndroidRelease"
    // Header Values
    private val REQ_HEADER_VALUE = "emax"
    // Labels
    private val LABEL_INIT = "Init RetrofitHelper"

    private var mBaseUrl: String
    private var mGson: Gson
    private var mRetrofit: Retrofit

    companion object {
        @Volatile private var mInstance: RetrofitHelper? = null

        fun getInstance() = mInstance

        fun initInstance(baseUrl: String): RetrofitHelper =
            mInstance ?: synchronized(this){
                mInstance ?: newInstance(baseUrl).also { mInstance = it }
            }

        private fun newInstance(baseUrl: String) = RetrofitHelper(baseUrl)
    }

    init {
        LogUtils.iLog(TAG, "START $LABEL_INIT")
        val httpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        httpClient.addInterceptor( getInterceptor() )
        httpClient.addInterceptor( getLoggingInterceptor() )
        this.mBaseUrl = baseUrl
        mGson = getGson()
        mRetrofit = getRetrofit(httpClient.build())
        LogUtils.iLog(TAG, "END $LABEL_INIT")
    }

    /* START Private Methods */
    private fun getRetrofit(httpClient: OkHttpClient): Retrofit{
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(mBaseUrl)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(mGson))
            .client(httpClient)
            .build()
    }

    private fun getGson(): Gson{
        return GsonBuilder()
            .setDateFormat(Constants.DATETIME_FORMAT_DB)
            .registerTypeAdapter(Boolean::class.javaObjectType, BooleanDeserializer())
            .create()
    }

    private fun getLoggingInterceptor() =
        HttpLoggingInterceptor {
            getLoggingInterceptorLogger()
        }.also { it.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY }

    private fun getLoggingInterceptorLogger() =
        HttpLoggingInterceptor.Logger {
                message -> HyperLog.v(TAG, message)
        }

    private fun getInterceptor(): Interceptor =
        Interceptor {
            buildInterceptorResponse(it)
        }

    private fun buildInterceptorResponse(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        val builder: Request.Builder = chain.request().newBuilder().addHeader(REQ_HEADER_NAME, REQ_HEADER_VALUE)
        setRequestHeaderVersionName(builder)
        setRequestHeaderVersionCode(builder)
        setRequestHeaderDeviceIMEI(builder)
        setRequestHeaderDeviceUniqueID(builder)
        setRequestHeaderDeviceModel(builder)
        setRequestHeaderAndroidRelease(builder)

        /* This part let you set custom timeout for different api call inside the "RetrofitAPI" interface using that labels: (example inside the RetrofitAPI interface)

public interface RetrofitAPI {

@Headers({RetrofitHelper.CONNECT_TIMEOUT + ":100000", RetrofitHelper.READ_TIMEOUT + ":100000"})
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST
    Call<JsonObject> doBaseJsonRequest(@Url String url, @Field("params") String params);

}
*/
        var connectTimeout = chain.connectTimeoutMillis()
        var readTimeout = chain.readTimeoutMillis()
        var writeTimeout = chain.writeTimeoutMillis()
        val request = chain.request()
        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(request.header(CONNECT_TIMEOUT))){
            connectTimeout = request.header(CONNECT_TIMEOUT)!!.toInt()
        }
        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(request.header(READ_TIMEOUT))){
            readTimeout = request.header(READ_TIMEOUT)!!.toInt()
        }
        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(request.header(WRITE_TIMEOUT))){
            writeTimeout = request.header(WRITE_TIMEOUT)!!.toInt()
        }
        builder.removeHeader(CONNECT_TIMEOUT)
        builder.removeHeader(READ_TIMEOUT)
        builder.removeHeader(WRITE_TIMEOUT)
        return chain
            .withConnectTimeout(connectTimeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .withReadTimeout(readTimeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .withWriteTimeout(writeTimeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .proceed(builder.build())
    }

    /*private fun setRequestHeaders(builder: Request.Builder): Request.Builder{
        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(AppEnvironment.getInstance()!!.mVersionName)){
            builder.addHeader(REQ_HEADER_VERSION_NAME, AppEnvironment.getInstance()!!.mVersionName!!)
        }
        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(AppEnvironment.getInstance()!!.mVersionCode.toString())){
            builder.addHeader(REQ_HEADER_VERSION_CODE, AppEnvironment.getInstance()!!.mVersionName!!)
        }
        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(AppEnvironment.getInstance()!!.mDeviceIMEI)){
            builder.addHeader(REQ_HEADER_DEVICE_IMEI, AppEnvironment.getInstance()!!.mVersionName!!)
        }
        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(AppEnvironment.getInstance()!!.mDeviceUniqueID)){
            builder.addHeader(REQ_HEADER_DEVICE_UNIQUE_ID, AppEnvironment.getInstance()!!.mVersionName!!)
        }
        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(AppEnvironment.getInstance()!!.mDeviceModel)){
            builder.addHeader(REQ_HEADER_DEVICE_MODEL, AppEnvironment.getInstance()!!.mVersionName!!)
        }
        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(AppEnvironment.getInstance()!!.mAndroidRelease)){
            builder.addHeader(REQ_HEADER_ANDROID_RELEASE, AppEnvironment.getInstance()!!.mVersionName!!)
        }
        return builder
    }*/

    private fun setRequestHeaderVersionName(builder: Request.Builder){
        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(AppEnvironment.getInstance()!!.mVersionName)){
            builder.addHeader(REQ_HEADER_VERSION_NAME, AppEnvironment.getInstance()!!.mVersionName!!)
        }
    }

    private fun setRequestHeaderVersionCode(builder: Request.Builder){
        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(AppEnvironment.getInstance()!!.mVersionCode.toString())){
            builder.addHeader(REQ_HEADER_VERSION_CODE, AppEnvironment.getInstance()!!.mVersionName!!)
        }
    }

    private fun setRequestHeaderDeviceIMEI(builder: Request.Builder){
        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(AppEnvironment.getInstance()!!.mDeviceIMEI)){
            builder.addHeader(REQ_HEADER_DEVICE_IMEI, AppEnvironment.getInstance()!!.mVersionName!!)
        }
    }

    private fun setRequestHeaderDeviceUniqueID(builder: Request.Builder){
        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(AppEnvironment.getInstance()!!.mDeviceUniqueID)){
            builder.addHeader(REQ_HEADER_DEVICE_UNIQUE_ID, AppEnvironment.getInstance()!!.mVersionName!!)
        }
    }

    private fun setRequestHeaderDeviceModel(builder: Request.Builder){
        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(AppEnvironment.getInstance()!!.mDeviceModel)){
            builder.addHeader(REQ_HEADER_DEVICE_MODEL, AppEnvironment.getInstance()!!.mVersionName!!)
        }
    }

    private fun setRequestHeaderAndroidRelease(builder: Request.Builder){
        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(AppEnvironment.getInstance()!!.mAndroidRelease)){
            builder.addHeader(REQ_HEADER_ANDROID_RELEASE, AppEnvironment.getInstance()!!.mVersionName!!)
        }
    }
    /* END Private Methods */

}
```

## LINK TO MY COMMENT FOR ASYNC RETROFIT USAGE WITH GENERIC TYPES METHODS AND CALLBACK INTERFACES:

[RETROFIT ASYNC WITH GENERIC TYPES](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54480807/9993413)
(This is in java but you can easily translate it in Kotlin! Also I suggest you to learn Java too because Kotlin is a scripting language built up Java so it translates the code in Java operations whose sometimes are really bigger (and sometimes slower) than if you wrote the code in Java! So, now I am learning Kotlin after learned Java for android applications, Kotlin is a really good, smart, beautiful and fast programming language for apps and I will use it to do fast and smart scripts inside my applications or for simple applications, but I will use Java too because with it you can generate faster code.

Hope this is helpful,
Bye and Good Coding! (:

Comment: There's a lot of useless information in this reply. The text formatting isn't nice either. Please update your reply and be to the point with what you want to share.

Comment: @Z3R0 Thanks for your anwer. I know Java too, so I can convert to Kotlin but could you be specific so that I can get a clear understanding. I just want to separate the data and view layer. If possible do help

Comment: @Amrutha J Raj as I said in the answer you need to use AsyncTask to do the networking operations (or other data operations) in another thread different from the activity. Also you can start a new thread using: " Thread( Runnable(...)).start() ", but I suggest you to use AsyncTasks (: I think , if I understood what you're searching, in the answer you can fin all the things you need (I am at work so I haven't too much time, I was just looking for a thing about bluetooth pairing and I saw your post so I decided to answer because I had all the code at hand ^^). hope this is helpful

Comment: This does not answer the question since the `AsyncTask` run in the `Activity`. What was asked for was a way to decouple the work from the `Activity`, An MVC or MVP approach  will do that as  I suggested in my answer using the Android Jetpack

Comment: No.. AsyncTask work in a thread out of the Activity Thread (UIThread)...
The code is in the activity, but it works in another thread, you get the result through the callback in the uithread after the asynctask's thread ended...

That's all. To Have a thread out of the UIThread you have to do that. For me "a way to decouple the work from the Activity" means "do, in this case, networking operations in a thread out of the UIThread. No?"

Comment: At the end he wrote: "But I don't want to put all the work in the activity thread", so the AsyncTask or start a new Thread do what he is asked. I'm wrong? If he is asking to do UI changes out LiveData, Observable ecc (as you answered) is the right choiche, but as he wrote I understood that he was asking a way to do networking operations in a different thread

Comment: In your code the AsyncTask has a Composition type of relation to the Activity. Your correct in the way that AsyncTask is not running in the Activity thread in it´s own thread, but still it lives in the Activity "Composition", The LiveData decouple stuff and makes it an [Aggregation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UI6lqHOVHic) type

Comment: Ok thanks, but you can use the LiveData to return the networking operation answer... To do the networking operations you still need to use a Thread or an AsyncTask... Personally I normally use callback interfaces to return data from a networking operations, I use LiveData if I have multiple activities or fragments running together, or if I need to update the UI directly by using MutableLiveData and Observers... Anyway I though he was asking for a way to do networking outside of the activity (as he wrote in the "getAppList()" method), so sorry if my answer is useless

Comment: I think we are both right, i just took it a bit further, and yes the AsyncTask  is needed in both approaches. Forgot to mention that it is the [Android Jetpack Viewmodel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) in combination with the LIveData that creates the abstraction decoupling